# How can I detect copy and cut event in a textarea using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and want to detect if the user copy or cut the text from the given textarea.

```
<textarea ng-model="target"></textarea>
<p>{{ event }}</p>
```

How can I do this in Angular? I have made a [sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M61trhY9S0DLSwLB2k5q) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/QZ0AsXOieWKqyx8Wu1zP?p=preview)

```
<div >
    <textarea name='textArea' ng-cut="event=cut" ng-copy="event=copy" value='copy/cut me'" ng-model="value"></textarea>

    <p>event: {{event}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy option is to create a directive. For example

```
.directive('detectCutCopy', function() {
    return function(scope, element) {
        element.on('cut copy', function(e) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.event = e.type;
            });
        });
    };
})
```

and in your template

```
<textarea ng-model="target" detect-cut-copy></textarea>
```

Plunker ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/2h0MSVM4506vOGrGxclu?p=preview

Comment: there was no need of creating a directive.

Comment: @Jigs That's cool. I didn't realise Angular already provided the `ng-cut` and `ng-copy` directives.